# Join worksheets with less than X rows in excel with VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little bit of a problem with finding a solution with VBA coding. In summarize I have in an excel file with a ton of worksheets with different rows each one. I want to find a code that can join me the worksheets with less than 20 rows into one, but the new worksheets cannot have more than 20 rows. I will give you an example to make it easier to understand:

**What I have**

Sheet1 - 10 rows

Sheet2 - 16 rows

Sheet3 - 50 rows

Sheet4 - 9 rows

Sheet5 - 5 rows

Sheet6 - 5 rows

**What I want**

Sheet2 - 16 rows

Sheet3 - 50 rows

MergedSheet1and4 - 19 rows

MergedSheet5and6 - 10 rows

I don't know if it is possible to do this but any help is more than welcome.
Thank you so much

Comment: Can you show me the code that you have tried so far please? I should be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: how many columns does the data have in each sheet?

Comment: What's your logic for **not** merging 1,5 & 6 to get 20 rows or 4,5 & 6 to get 19 rows, for example?

Comment: Hey, Glitch_Doctor I still don't have any working code for this problem, in fact I don't know how to reach the problem. mo.h every sheet have 15 columns. Skip Intro the logic I applied is the first worksheets merge with the next ones available, but it's not mandatory, it can be in that way you presented. Thank you so much guys